# What activation function to use or modifications to make when neural network gives same output on regression with PyBrain?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I have a neural network with one input, three hidden neurons and one output. I have 720 input and corresponding target values, 540 for training, 180 for testing.
When I train my network using Logistic Sigmoid or Tan Sigmoid function, I get the same outputs while testing, i.e. I get same number for all 180 output values. When I use Linear activation function, I get NaN, because apparently, the value gets too high.

Is there any activation function to use in such a case? Or any improvements to be done? I can update the question with details and code if required.

Comment: Can you post a plot of your input/output pairs?

Comment: @Dougal: You mean, input vs. target plot? Or individual plots of inputs and targets?

Comment: Input vs target. Each is 1d, right?

Comment: @Dougal: Yes. I'll post the plot.

Comment: @Dougal: Since I needed 10 reputation points to post a photo, I couldn't do it here. Here's a link to the plot (x-axis is inputs, y-axis is targets):
http://s1369.photobucket.com/user/vivekmehta2612/media/ann_zps6ceecb75.png.html?filters[user]=140926618&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural nets are not stable when fed input data on arbitrary scales (such as between approximately 0 and 1000 in your case). If your output units are tanh they can't even predict values outside the range -1 to 1 or 0 to 1 for logistic units!

You should try recentering/scaling the data (making it have mean zero and unit variance - this is called standard scaling in the datascience community). Since it is a lossless transformation you can revert back to your original scale once you've trained the net and predicted on the data.

Additionally, a linear output unit is probably the best as it makes no assumptions about the output space and I've found tanh units to do much better on recurrent neural networks in low dimensional input/hidden/output nets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Newmu. Can you please elaborate how I can perform the scaling/recentering using Python or Pybrain?

Comment: Once I get the outputs, how to convert them to the previous scale?

Answer (score 1):

Newmu is right that the scaling is probably the issue here; you need to scale your inputs to lie in the valid range. (Standardization to zero mean, unit variance, as they suggest, though, isn't a great choice since that means about a third of your data will like outside [-1, 1]....) I don't know about pybrain, but in scikit-learn you'd want [`sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).

But, also, in the comments you said your dataset looks like this:

[image: dataset]

where the horizontal axis is inputs, vertical is targets. So, when you see an input of 200, you have one training example saying it's 80 and one saying it's 320; what do you want it to say then? An "optimal" neural network (which may be hard to achieve) would predict 200 or so.

You may need to think about how to reframe your learning problem to be a more-consistent function from inputs to targets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Dougal. Actually, the x-axis is targets and y-axis is inputs. I made an error in typing and am not able to edit the comment now. Can you suggest me what exactly I should do to get close output values? I am relatively new to ANN and so, don't know much about the topic.